# jquery incrementing value .click() with a maximum and minimum

Tags: jquery, click, increment

I have a slider where I need to move the background-position on click. This is my code so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var count = 0;
$(".slider-next").click(function() {
    var position = count + 150;
   $(".slider").css("background-position", position + "0");
});
    $(".slider-prev").click(function() {
        var position = count - 150;
    $(".slider").css("background-position", position + "0");
});

});
```

I need for the position to increment by 150 on each click of slider-next and decrease by 150 on each click of slider-prev. I also need to set a maximum so the position will never go above 2700 or below 0. 
link to codepen to see all of the code: https://codepen.io/jessiemele/pen/RgxQVx

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: i'll add it to my question now

Comment: are you sing jquery slider?

Comment: ("background-position", position + "0") .. why are you appending "0" to the position

Comment: Omi - not using jquery slider

Comment: praveen - appending "0" because that is the y value, the "position" is the x value

Comment: then you need to add your css here

Comment: omi- added my css

Comment: please provide your slider HTML content complete with images. easy to us just coding

Comment: Kamarul - here is a link to it on codepen: https://codepen.io/jessiemele/pen/RgxQVx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there was two simple mistakes:

1. Your counter is not getting increment on next it was just 150 all times.
2. Your are not using px to set background position. syntax to update position is `background-position: 50px 100px;`

```js
var count = 0,min=0,max=2700;
  $(".slider-next").click(function() {
   if(count<=max) {
     count += 150;
     $(".slider").css('background-position', count +'px 0px');
     }
 });
   $(".slider-prev").click(function() {
    if(count>min){
   count = count - 150;
    $(".slider").css("background-position", count + "px 0px");
      }
 });
```

```css
.slider {
 width: 550px;
 height: 125px;
 position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: url(https://stage.dmipartners.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/services-logos.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.controls {
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
.slider-nav {
 position: relative;
}
.slider-prev {
 position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
}
.slider-next {
 position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
}
.slider-next, .slider-prev {
 display: block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #2C89A5;
 color: #FFF;
    background: #869791;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="slider">
 <div class="controls">
    <div class="slider-prev">‹</div>
   <div class="slider-next">›</div>
 </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Do you know how I can set a maximum value for count, for example if the value is equal to -2700 or lower it prevents the div from being clickable?

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the value of `count`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var count = 0;
$(".slider-next").click(function() {
    var position = count + 150;
    count += 150;
   $(".slider").css("background-position", position + "0");
});
    $(".slider-prev").click(function() {
        var position = count - 150;
        count -= 150;
    $(".slider").css("background-position", position + "0");
});

});
```

Comment: this is changing the value of count but it isn't changing the position value in the .css line

Comment: what's your browser?

Comment: I'm using chrome now but have access to all of them

Comment: Your jquery version please! It seems that it's deprecated now

Comment: I'm using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry, i can't figure out how to make this work on this version. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go mate: https://codepen.io/nitinsuri/pen/WOdMLq. If you check the console at the URL that you shared, it says $ not defined. So I added the jQuery library.

Once that is done, I've replaced

```
$(".slider").css("background-position", position + "0");
```

with:

```
$(".slider").css("background-position-x", position);
```

Hope this helps you.